# PlayingError: Error: Cannot find module when trying to run a play command

Tags: discord, discord.js

I have `@discordjs/opus` installed and I'm trying to access it to play music. I'm running on Replit and it worked fine when I was testing it so I'm guessing it has some issue with that.

````
Error: Cannot find module '/home/runner/omex/node_modules/@discordjs/opus/prebuild/node-v93-napi-v3-linux-x64-glibc-2.24/opus.node```
````

Comment: I'm having the same issue with a replit bot after updating node (worked fine for months before). Removing the package and reinstalling it hasn't helped. I'll post a response if I find an answer while I'm looking today.

Answer (score 1):

I debugged through my instance where I was having the same issue and it looked like all of the following @discordjs/opus, node-opus and opusscript were failing so I looked in Packages (left side of replit screen, the icon looks like a 3D cube) for node-opus and opusscript.

node-opus wasn't in the list, so I installed opusscript 0.0.8 and it started working again instantly. YMMV, but let me know if this fixes your issue.